# Showing that a minimization problem is unbounded

Tags: convex-optimization

Let $s^*=\mathrm{inf}\Bigl\lbrace{\frac{1}{2}x^TMx+v^Tx+w:x \in \mathbb{R}^n\Bigr\rbrace}$ be a minimization problem with $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $w \in \mathbb{R}$.

How to show:

If $M$ is positive semidefinite and $Mx^*=-v$ has no solution, it's $s^*=-\infty$.

My idea was:

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TMx+v^Tx+w$.

It's $\nabla f(x)=Mx+v$, so there is no maximum or minimum point which means it has to be unbounded. But I don't see why it's $s^*=-\infty$.

Is this way corrrect or how can it be shown properly?

Comment: Write $v=v_1+v_2$ where $v_1 \in \ker M$ and $v_2 \in ({\cal R}M)^\bot$. Then consider $f(-tv_1)= -t \|v_1\|^2 +w$. You need to understand and justify these steps, of course.

Comment: What happens with $$M = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \\ \end{array} \right) $$   and $v = \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right) $   and $w = 17  \; \; \; ?  $

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean with $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: It is the range space of the following matrix.